# list.find question

Tags: c#

I am trying to run this code, but `a` is always `null`. I made sure that there's a `Name`, why does it always return null?

```
   public  Animal FindAnimal(string Name)
    {
        Animal a = Animals.Find(

            delegate(Animal bk)
            {
                return bk.AnimalName.ToLower() == Name.ToLower();
            }


            );
        return a;

    }
```

Comment: What does the `Animal` type look like?  What's in your list of `Animals`?  What `Name` are you searching for?

Comment: Heres a suggestion: Use String.Compare instead of converting to lower or upper case.

Comment: Is this intended that the delegate method returns a boolean?

Comment: I use the same example in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me. Here are some small optimizations though:

```
public Animal FindAnimal(string name)
{
    return Animals.Find((a) => String.Equals(a.AnimalName, name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

**EDIT**
Test of code:

```
void Main()
{
     var foundAnimal = FindAnimal("Monkey"); //Not null
}

List<Animal> Animals = new List<Animal>(){ new Animal() { AnimalName = "Monkey" }};

public Animal FindAnimal(string name)
{
    return Animals.Find((a) => String.Equals(a.AnimalName, name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
}   
public class Animal
{
    public string AnimalName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I create list of animals then try to find , I don't have any other code , U mean the animal class